# Error on adjusting jpeg quality: Value cannot be null.Parameter name: structure

Tags: c#

I have a method where I take an image, make a copy for resizing, and then return it as a byte array. I have attempted to add the ability to adjust the quality of the image per this doc:

[http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb882583(v=vs.110).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb882583%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

```
Image image = Image.FromFile(_filepath);

Image newImage = new Bitmap(newWidth, newHeight);
using (Graphics graphicsHandle = Graphics.FromImage(newImage))
{
    graphicsHandle.InterpolationMode = InterpolationMode.HighQualityBicubic;
    graphicsHandle.DrawImage(image, 0, 0, newWidth, newHeight);
}
MemoryStream memStream = new MemoryStream();

EncoderParameters myEncoderParameters = new EncoderParameters(1);

ImageCodecInfo encoder = ImageCodecInfo.GetImageDecoders().SingleOrDefault(c => c.MimeType == contentType);
System.Drawing.Imaging.Encoder myEncoder = System.Drawing.Imaging.Encoder.Quality;
EncoderParameter myEncoderParameter = new EncoderParameter(myEncoder, 50L);
newImage.Save(memStream, encoder, myEncoderParameters);

return memStream.ToArray();
```

When I call `newImage.Save()`, I get this error:

> An exception of type 'System.ArgumentNullException' occurred in System.Drawing.dll but was not handled in user code

Message is:

> Value cannot be null.
>   Parameter name: structure

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms142148%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) says that you have a ArgumentNullException when calling this Save() overload only if the stream is *NULL*.

Are you sure that no other (omitted?) code is not nullifying this stream?
Are you sure this is the site of the exception?

Comment: That's what I was looking at, but it turns out I didn't add the proper parameter to my parameter collection, and you snuck in an answer before I had a chance to delete this question ;)

Answer (score 2):

Forgot a step. I created the `EncoderParameter` object, but didn't include it in the `EncoderParameters` collection. The message confused me a bit.

All resolved once I added:

```
myEncoderParameters.Param[0] = myEncoderParameter;
```

Comment: This saved me so much trouble. Such a simple oversight, but thank you for pointing it out!